# Generating URL for AJAX query based on checkboxes and dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an options panel that looks like this:

[image]

Attached is my HTML code:

HTML

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Times You Don't Want Classes</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body panel-options">
        <div id="days" class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"> Mon
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"> Tues
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"> Wed
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"> Thurs
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"> Fri
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">

            <a id="from-text" class="btn btn-default">10:00 AM</a>
            <a data-target="#" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul id="from" class="dropdown-menu time-span">
                // These are simply time increments from 7 AM to midnight
                @foreach ($timeIncrements as $increment)
                    <li><a href="#">{{ $increment }}</a></li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
        to
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a id="to-text" class="btn btn-default">12:00 PM</a>
            <a data-target="#" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul id="to" class="dropdown-menu time-span">
                @foreach ($timeIncrements as $increment)
                    <li><a href="#">{{ $increment }}</a></li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is, when the user clicks the Monday.. Tuesday.. Wednesday.. and the from-and-to times, to generate a URL for my AJAX code to query that particular URL.

My API looks like the following URL:

```
example.org/schedulizer/schedule?from=1000&to=1200&days=MW
```

As you can see, `from` and `to` are the spans in which the user does not want classes (so 10 AM to 12 PM in our case)

`days` are the days they want the span to satisfy (Monday and Wednesday in our case)

This is what I have so far for my JS

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        $('#from li').on('click', function(){
            $('#from-text').text($(this).text());
        });

        $('#to li').on('click', function(){
            $('#to-text').text($(this).text());
        });

        $(function(){
            $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
                var item=$(this);
                if(item.is(":checked"))
                {
                    console.log($('#days').attr('value'));
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am quite new to Javascript, so I am quite lost on how to begin. How would I take the values from the checkboxes and dropdowns and generate a URL based on what's selected?

Comment: There is a lot of work to do. Not magic.

Comment: If the expected params in the URL are `from=1000&to=1200&days=MW`, how do you know that **1000** is 10 AM or 10 PM, or **T** is Tuesday or Thursday? Anyway, you can start adding a `value` for each checkbox.

Comment: Yes, I'll need to add values to the checkboxes and dropdowns.

Comment: Add ID's to your checkboxes and dropdowns and evaluate the checkboxes `checked` attribute and the select's `val()`